# How to create hierarchical wiki in git lab

Tags: gitlab, wiki

How to create a hierarchical wiki pages in GitLab

```
Home
    <Wiki Page 1>
    <Wiki Page 2>
    <Wiki Page 3>
       <Wiki Page 3 - 1>
       <Wiki Page 3 - 2>
    <Wiki Page 4>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can specify wiki page path in page title field, for example `section/section/wiki page`.

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/wiki/#move-a-wiki-page for details.